# Getting inferior process message which I don't understand

Tags: gdb, gnu

I am using gnu tools and gdb on Linux Mint19.1 along with the book "Programming From the Ground Up". I have run the program maximum.s through the compiler and linker and got the correct answer. However when I try to step through the program with gdb I get the message: inferior process 1 (process 18754) exited with code 0336. Help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: as --gstabs maximum.s -o maximum.0 and ld -o maximum.s -o maximum.o was added to include debugging info – bill lawhorn

Answer (score 1):

> However when I try to step through the program with gdb I get the message: `inferior process 1 (process 18754) exited with code 0336.`

The message means: the process you were debugging (with process id `18754`) has exited (called `exit` of `exit_group` system call), with code `0336` (`222` in decimal).

The most likely reason this happened: you did `step` (which requires debugging info to be present, and your program doesn't have any).

You *probably* wanted to step one instruction at at time, and the command for that is `stepi`.

Comment: as --gstabs maximum.s -o maximum.0  and ld -o maximum.s -o maximum.o was added to include debugging info